# Storing functions and their parameters in an array to call later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to store multiple functions and their parameters in an array that I will later loop over and execute. When putting the parens around the parameters, the function executes immediately and its array value becomes undefined. I would like to prevent this from happening and call the function (with its parameter(s)) at a later time. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish...

```
function getTableAssignments(callbacks) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        datatype: "jsonp",
        url: base_url + "users/getTableAssignments/" + event_id
    }).done(function (data) {
        tables = data;
        if (callbacks.length > 0) {
            $.each(callbacks, function (i, v) {
                v();
            });
        }
    });
}
getTableAssignments([func1(param1, param2), func2, func3(param3)]);
```

Comment: `tables` is for fun?

Comment: yes, global var i didn't list in my example

Answer (score 2):

Storing the parameters is the problem. Here is how to store the function references:

```
getTableAssignments([func1, func2, func3]);
```

Here is how to *bind* the parameters to the functions prior to execution. This returns a new function. There are other ways to do it, but I think this would be the simplest.

```
var boundFunc1 = func1.bind(null, param1, param2);
var boundFunc3 = func3.bind(null, param3);

getTableAssignments([boundFunc2, func2, boundFunc3]);
```

You can also store your parameters in an object as arrays, and lookup those stored parameters with the function name, but that seems messy, so I won't expound on that method (and it would require you to change the calling to code the lookup the parameters).

If you haven't read up on bind, I'd recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhbhD1HR5vk)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use function expressions:

```
getTableAssignments([
    function() {func1(param1, param2); },
    func2,
    function() {func3(param3); }
]);
```

Comment: `.bind()` will also work. i.e. `func1.bind(null, param1, param2)`

Comment: True, there are multiple ways to skin the cat.

Comment: Definitely - just wanted to make a note of it for other viewers. `.bind()` will also reduce call stack overhead (although the difference would likely be negligible)

Comment: @mhodges Someone else posted that method as an answer, so it's already noted more visibly.

Answer (score 1):

I think arrow functions would be a slick way of doing this:

```js
function func1 (param) {
 console.log("func1 : " + param);
}
function func2 () {
 console.log("func2");
}
function func3 (param1, param2) {
 console.log("func3 : " + param1 + ", " + param2);
}

function executeFunctions(funcs) {
 for (var i = 0, len = funcs.length; i < len; i++) {
  funcs[i]();
 }
}

favorateParam = "bob";
executeFunctions([
 ()=>func1("dad"),
 ()=>func2(),
 ()=>func3("jane",favorateParam)
]);
```

Comment: If you used the approach you suggest above can you expand on this a bit and give an example of how you would actually call the function that was stored in the array?